# Android getJSONObject reordered automatic

Tags: android, json

I use below code :

```
JSONObject value = ...;
JSONObject stationList = value.getJSONObject("stationList");

Iterator<String> iter = array.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    try {
        String key = iter.next();
        String val = array.get(key).toString();

        Log.i("res", key+"- "+val);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My data sort is :

```
1- name
3- other
2- your
```

But output is :

```
1- name
2- your
3- other
```

I think JSONObject reorder data with integer key.

How I can fix it and read data without reorder?

Comment: there are not any order for map

Answer (score 0):

JSONObjects are similar to map which stores data as a key value pair without maintaining order.

Comment: How I can fix it?